# Using SQL history function in historian database

Tags: sql, oracle

In attempt to query data from a local table created from a historian database I found the following code..

```
'select a1.TS,                                                       
        a1.value
   from history     a1,
        history(80) a2'
```

I know that the corresponding variable for a.1 is char(40) type. My question is what is history(80) mean?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your syntax is incomplete. Would you mind posting all of the Select? The (80) is a parameter, I think the history is a function but I could be wrong without looking at all of it.

Comment: You will probably find there is a Table-valued Function in your database. I suspect there is a Function called history, which takes a parameter, maybe of a column-length, which here is being specified as 80 characters long. Search in Database-->Programmability-->Functions-->Table-valued Functions for an object named history.

Comment: Run `select * from user_objects where object_name like 'HISTORY'` - that may give you some clues. You may find a function or a procedure or who-knows-what by the name HISTORY - then you can take it from there.

Comment: If i try the following I receive an error that user_object does not exist.
`select * from USER_OBJECT where object_name like 'HISTORY';`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging I found that the reason why I need to access data from a HISTORY table is because the historian database does not collect data at equal time intervals. A HISTORY table is a compressed version of the database at regular intervals.

The max size of a column in the history table is 80. This must be passed through history if character data is being accessed.